# Css align left, center and right, not working

Tags: html, css

Here is what i am trying to do:
I want the css to show divs like this:

Left(show  logo here)       Center(show left,mid,right divs here together)     right(show return here)

I have following code:

```
<div id="top" class="top">                
                <asp:Panel ID="Srch" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Wrap="False">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="logo" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/logo.gif" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="left"></div>
                    <div id="mid">
                        <asp:textbox id="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
            <asp:button id="find" runat="server" Text="find"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right"></div>                    
                    <div id="return">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="i" runat="server" Text="return"></asp:HyperLink>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>                                
            </div>
```

here is css i have so far:

```
#Srch
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:10px;   
    height: 35px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:19px;
    width: 100%;
    border:thick solid black; 
}
#left
{
    position:absolute;
    background:  url(/images/searchBG_left_10x35.png) repeat-x;
    top: 15px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    left:50%;    
}
#mid
{
    position:absolute;
    background: url(/images/searchBG_mid_1x35.png) repeat-x;
    top: 15px;
    height: 35px;
    float:left;
}
#right
{
    position:absolute;
    background: url(/images/searchBG_right_10x35.png) repeat-x;
    top: 15px;
    width:9px;
    height:35px;
    float:left;
}
#return
{
    position:absolute;
    float: right;
    top: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: Blue;
}
#logo
{  
    position:absolute;
    float: left;   
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#txtS
{
    width: 285px;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    margin-right:3px;
}
#find
{
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 50px;
    height: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put another div that contains the *left*, *mid* and *right* div's yyou can try something like this:
**HTML**

```
<div ID="Srch">
    <div id="logo"> </div>
    <div id="medio">
        <div id="left"> </div>
        <div id="mid"> </div>
        <div id="right"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="return"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Srch{
    padding-left: 20em;
    padding-right: 22em;
}

#logo{
    float: left;
    width: 20em;
    margin-left: -20em;
}

#medio{
    float: left;
}

#return{
    float: left;
    width: 22em;
    margin-right: -22em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute;` removes elements from the regular flow of the document, so you can't `float` them.

Here is an example of the layout you are trying to achieve using [`float`](http://dabblet.com/gist/1717698) and one using [`position:absolute;`](http://dabblet.com/gist/1717710)

Comment: @bookcasey- i tried removing float and put in position:absolute. It kinda shows the way i want it. But when i chage browser size it is all over the place. Is there a better way to do it? So that it works on all browser sizes?